# Can't detect checkbox selection with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox

I'm trying to use JQuery to detect when a checkbox is selected or not. The JS I'm using is like so:

```
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
    if (this.checked){
      console.log("checked!");
    } else {
      console.log("not checked!");
    }
});
```

The checkbox in my HTML:

```
<input class="tgl tgl-skewed" id="cb3" type="checkbox"/>
<label class="tgl-btn" data-tg-off="$" data-tg-on="฿" for="cb3"> </label>
```

In the JS console I am getting the error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like you've not included the jQuery library

Comment: Yes, the code works perfectly fine, you just need to include JQuery library;

Comment: I've included JQuery. It's not the only place I'm using it. The other JQuery code works fine.

Comment: what are your data attributes doing? Does the reference error relate to the `$` in the `data-tg-off` attribute? I'm also pretty sure you can't be using a bitcoin symbol. try and change that stuff to actual alpha (cash, coins ?)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#cb3").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
      console.log("checked!");
    } else {
      console.log("not checked!");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<input class="tgl tgl-skewed" id="cb3" type="checkbox"/>
<label class="tgl-btn" data-tg-off="$" data-tg-on="฿" for="cb3"> </label>
```

Comment: @Kex It's Okay.. Check Twice Please.